# How do I despawn a rendered model in SceneForm?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am new to SceneForm. I have created a code that renders a model when user taps on a point on screen. How do I remove this model on say, when user taps a clear all button. 
Here is my spawn function

```
 private void addModeltoScene(ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {


    TransformableNode transformableNode = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode);
    transformableNode.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
    //now add to scene
    arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
    transformableNode.select();



}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arFrameFragment.arSceneView.scene.removeChild(node)
```

Where `node` is [AnchorNode](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/AnchorNode) for your 3D model and 
`arFrameFragment` is [ArFragment](https://developers.google.com/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ArFragment)

Comment: There is no arSceneView instance

Comment: In Java: arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene()